# Visual Studio Code suddenly produced an incompatibility error

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, undefined-reference

I've been working on a C++ program, and initially, everything was functioning smoothly. However, I recently encountered an issue with the following error message:

> This version of .exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

Surprisingly, I haven't made any changes to my code. Strangely, when I run `.cpp` files, everything is fine, but the problem arises when I run `.h` files.

I'm using the MingW compiler, Code Runner, and Visual Studio Code.

Any insights or suggestions?

I think I accidentally clicked somewhere in Visual Studio Code and made an unintended change!

I reinstalled Visual Studio and the MingW compiler, but I am still encountering the same issue.

---

I got a new error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

board.cpp

```
#include "board.h"

void Board::placePiece(const Square& square, const Piece& piece, const Player& player)
{
    position.pieces[square] = piece;
    position.players[square] = player;
}

void Board::removePiece(const Square& square)
{
    position.pieces[square] = empty;
    position.players[square] = none;
}
```

board.h

```
#include "../utils/definitions.h"
#include "config.h"

class Board
{

    protected:

        void placePiece(const Square& square, const Piece& piece, const Player& player);
        void removePiece(const Square& square);

};
```

Comment: Just curious, why would you run a .h file?

Comment: to see if I get an error or not!

Comment: Do you mean *compilation* of .cpp files, editing them or actual execution (running) of the source files?  Usually, cpp files are compiled and linked to form an executable.  The executable is run by the operating system

Comment: I press Ctrl + Alt + N.

Comment: Don't do that.  .H files aren't intended to be compiled.  They are only included in other files.  Further, in most cases you can't even "run" single CPP files by themselves.  They have to be compiled together as a unit.

Comment: In one to the terminal windows, VS Code will spit out the full build output, all the diagnostics and all the command lines. The build output would probably be the most useful thing to add to the question because it will show us how the executable is being built.

Comment: Side note: VS Code is not that forgiving to new programmers. If it's available on your development system, consider using it's (also free) big brother [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) or runni8ng without an IDE and learning how the C++ build systems generally wrk from the command line.

Comment: Side note: mingw32/6.3.0 in the path you show suggests you didn't follow the [official installation documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). If you had, you'd be using GCC13. GCC6.3 is an antique compiler at this point, so you're accidentally limiting yourself.

Comment: "Run active file" is absolutely horrible option for C++. I wish Code Runner did something smarter, like getting all files in directory recursively and compiling them together. Short answer: the program you are trying to link has no definition of `int main()` function. For long answer we don't have enough details.

Comment: but I don't need main() function. I want to include it in another file

Comment: My advice is 1. don't use code-runner (it does not handle more than 1 source file in a good way) and 2. Use the official instructions and follow the section here which tells you how to fix this problem: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: @DanielZ. Every once in a while I'll compile a complicated header file to make sure it is as self-consistent as I think it is.

Comment: *I want to include it in another file* [Then you're right on schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249). Board.cpp and board.h and whatever ../utils/definitions.h is all compile. The error you have is an error raised during the linking stage, and you will not be able to successfully link the program until you have at least one other file, probably the one using `Board`, with a `main` function defined. This calls back to @drescherjm 's comment above about editing task.json. If you don't follow those instructions you won't be able to link more than one file.

Comment: "the problem arises when I run .h files" - How does one even *do* that? Why is that even a thing one would want to do? Puzzled..

Comment: [Does Visual Studio Rot the Mind?](https://charlespetzold.com/etc/DoesVisualStudioRotTheMind.html) explains what the fundamental issue is. The solution is to step away from VSCode for a while.